# Error when trying to loop and extract coefficients and p-values from large list or atomic vector of logistic regression results, r

Tags: r, loops, regression

I have a loop that produces 117 logistic regression models. That seems to be working correctly. However, now I want to write a loop that extracts the odds ratios and p-values for the odds ratios of all 117 models.
Here is the loop that produces the logistic regression models (I will be adding some more predictors soon, but getting the loops to work is the challenging part)

```
mdls<-lapply(metabolite.names, function(X) 
glm(as.formula(paste0("hpresponse1~",X)),
                                       data=df, family="binomial"))
```

That loop above appears to work correctly. Now I am trying to spit out the odds ratios and p-values for each model. I have tried this:

```
results<-lapply(mdls, function(p) coef(summary(mdls)))
```

I have also tried this:

```
results<-coef(summary(mdls))
```

They both produce the same error:

```
Error in object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What can I do to fix this and get the odds ratios and p-values in a summary format?

Comment: You need: `results<-lapply(mdls, function(p) coef(summary(p)))`.  Inside the `lapply()` you were trying to pass the entire `mdls` list instead of each element in turn.

Comment: consider `library(broom); library(purrr); names(mdls) <- metabolite.names; purrr_map_dfr(mdls, tidy, exponentiate = TRUE, .id = "metabolite")`